# Linux device driver read write functions issue

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm writing sample device driver to read and write using cyclic buffer, it means the last node point to the first one. I created the linked list of 10 block, each block buffer size = 5.

now on my write function, when I call write method, it write in the buffer, check if it's filled, then jump to the other one, the next write will write in the current buffer + offset defined in `lnod struct` . same thing for read.

when I run the echo command twice

```
echo 123456789 > /dev/driver
echo abcd > /dev/driver
```

according to the write and read function below the `cat` command will give`123456789abcd` as result since the second write will continue on the offset, so the read function will read all the `size_to_read`, but the `cat` (called 3 times)command gave me this :

```
cat /dev/driver 
abcd
6789
abcd
```

some usefull code parts:

```
static int BlockNumber = 10;
static int BlockSize = 5;

static int size_to_read = 0;
```

data buffer structure

```
 typedef struct dnode
 {
     int bufSize;
     char *buffer;
     struct dnode *next;
 } data_node;
```

liste stucture

```
 typedef struct  lnode
 {
     data_node *head;
     data_node *cur_write_node;
     data_node *cur_read_node;  
     int cur_read_offset;
     int cur_write_offset;
 }liste;

static liste newListe;
```

**the create liste method is called in init function**

write function

```
static ssize_t sample_write_liste(struct file *f, const char *buf, size_t size, loff_t *offset) 
{
    if (*(offset) == 0)  
    {
        size_to_read += size;
    }
    int size_to_copy;
    size_to_copy = MIN (size, BlockSize - newListe.cur_write_offset);
    copy_from_user(newListe.cur_write_node->buffer + newListe.cur_write_offset, buf, size_to_copy);
    *(offset) += size_to_copy;
    newListe.cur_write_offset +=  size_to_copy;
    if (newListe.cur_write_offset == BlockSize) 
    {
      newListe.cur_write_node = newListe.cur_write_node->next;
      newListe.cur_write_offset = 0;  // we erase previous things
    }
    return size_to_copy;
}
```

the read function

```
static ssize_t sample_read_liste(struct file *f, char *buf, size_t size, loff_t *offset)
{
    int size_to_copy;
    size_to_copy = MIN (size_to_read - *(offset), BlockSize - newListe.cur_read_offset);
    copy_to_user(buf, newListe.cur_read_node->buffer + newListe.cur_read_offset,size_to_copy);
    newListe.cur_read_offset += size_to_copy;
    (*offset)+=size_to_copy; 

    if (newListe.cur_read_offset == BlockSize) 
    {
        newListe.cur_read_node = newListe.cur_read_node->next;
        newListe.cur_read_offset = 0;
    }
    return size_to_copy;  
}
```

create linked list function

```
static void createlist (void) {
    data_node *newNode, *previousNode, *headNode;
    int i;
    /* new node creation  */
    newNode = (data_node *)kmalloc(sizeof (data_node), GFP_KERNEL);
    newNode->buffer = (char *)kmalloc(BlockSize*sizeof(char), GFP_KERNEL);
    newNode->next = NULL;

    newListe.head = newNode;
    headNode = newNode;
    previousNode = newNode;


    for (i = 1; i < BlockNumber; i++)
    {
        newNode = (data_node *)kmalloc(sizeof (data_node), GFP_KERNEL);
        newNode->buffer = (char *)kmalloc(BlockSize*sizeof(char), GFP_KERNEL);
        newNode->next = NULL;
        previousNode->next = newNode;
    }
    /* cyclic liste : we should tie the last element to the first one (head) */
    newNode->next = headNode;

    newListe.cur_read_node = headNode;
    newListe.cur_write_node = headNode;
    newListe.cur_read_offset = 0;
    newListe.cur_write_offset = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the  createlist() routine , in the for loop, you need to add the follwoing line to make a circular list.
previousNode = newNode;
Your existing createlist would create a circular list with just two nodes.

```
for (i = 1; i < BlockNumber; i++)
{
    newNode = (data_node *)kmalloc(sizeof (data_node), GFP_KERNEL);
    newNode->buffer = (char *)kmalloc(BlockSize*sizeof(char), GFP_KERNEL);
    newNode->next = NULL;
    previousNode->next = newNode;
    previousNode = newNode  //Please add this line to make the list circular.
}
```

Comment: it works thanks a lot but why it return back to line? when I run `echo gggg > /dev/driver` and `echo 444 > /dev/driver` , it display `gggg` and new line and `444`

Comment: echo is adding a new line at the end of your input. This can be verified by the follwong steps. echo gggg > some_txt_file. If you check the size of the some_txt_file it would be of 5 bytes, not 4 bytes.